# Disable pivot flick for WP7

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

seeing this blog post : http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=111, I'm trying to disable the pivot flick when flicking on a control inside the pivot.

I've tryed the proposed solution with IsHitTestVisible, but it seems that the application locks when setting it to false.

To reproduce the problem, create a wp7 basic application. Use this xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <controls:Pivot Name="pivotCtrl" Grid.Row="1">
                <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Text="{Binding Value1}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Text="{Binding Value2}" />
                            <Canvas Grid.Row="2" Width="400" Height="300" Background="Yellow" MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

with this code behing :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
            elements.Add(new Element { Value1 = "Value - " + i, Value2 = "Something - " + i});

        pivotCtrl.ItemsSource = elements;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("On");
        pivotCtrl.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Off");
        pivotCtrl.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    }
}

public class Element
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

In debug mode, I can see the "Off" value, but never the "On" one.

Maybe there's another solution for this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution was posted this week. Does it work better for you?

[Preventing the Pivot or Panorama controls from scrolling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/22/preventing-the-pivot-or-panorama-controls-from-scrolling.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)